"ERROR: Could not build wheels for signatory, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" on Mac OS Ventura
[Update:  I followed the solution mentioned in the GitHub issue #43 but it didn't work for me! Still causing the same error.]
I have PyTorch version 1.9.0 and I'm trying to install signatory version 1.2.6 on my Mac OS Ventura. I'm running the following command (reference: signatory installation) on the terminal creating a virtual environment:
pip install signatory==1.2.6.1.9.0 --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall

And that is giving me the following result:
    Downloading signatory-1.2.6.1.9.0.tar.gz (62 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 kB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: signatory
  Building wheel for signatory (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [111 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/signatory
      copying src/signatory/signature_inversion_module.py -> buil
      ...
      ...
      ...
                raise RuntimeError(message) from e
      RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for signatory
  Running setup.py clean for signatory
Failed to build signatory
ERROR: Could not build wheels for signatory, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


I've searched on Google but found no reference to this ERROR: Could not build wheels for signatory, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Found the solution! I'm writing step by step about my experience and what solved my issue in case anybody else is stuck on the same issue.
For MacOS, the command pip install signatory==1.2.6.1.9.0 --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall won't work. For MacOS, run the following commands instead(Thanks to the author amandlek):
brew install llvm

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.4.1 CC=clang CXX=clang++ pip install signatory==1.2.6.1.9.0 --no-binary signatory

Note that, here 13.4.1 is my MacOS version. The above lines of codes should successfully install signatory without any error. If not, read further.
Now in my case, I got an error after running the first line of code: zsh: command not found: brew So I had to install brew first on my Mac following this link. In summary, I had to run the following 3 lines of codes sequentially to install brew:
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
 
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
 
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

After running the above commands, MUST restart the device (which I didn't at first and I think that's why the error was still there) and then run the 5 lines of codes mentioned at the beginning.
So if the code using the brew doesn't work, try restarting your device and then again run only the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.4.1 CC=clang CXX=clang++ pip install signatory==1.2.6.1.9.0 --no-binary signatory command, that should successfully install signatory!
Note: It's a good and safe practice to do all of these inside a virtual environment.
